# Why I can't erase a hidden file with root privileges?

Tags: permissions

I downloaded a compressed file (rar) with two files inside:

1) A PDF standard file, and

2) A hidden file  **.fuse_hidden000004a90000000c** (a dot, not extension, file name), which is the exact same PDF file.

Well, I tried to remove (erase) the hidden file and... I couldn't!

I tried with root privileges (**sudo -i**) and... Nothing!

I tried **chmod** with **ugoa+rwx** to change all the parameters of that file and... Nothing!

Here is the "infamous" file, and I can't remove it!

Each time I type: **dir**, there is nothing.

But, when I type: **ls -a**, then I can see the hidden file!

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a permission problem. It seems you deleted the PDF while the file is still in use by some application. In this case (on fuse-based file systems), the file is deleted and a .fuse_hidden-file is created and kept as long as someone is using the file (there is at least one open file descriptor referencing the file). This mimics the common concept of delayed deletion (you can delete an open file, it will disappear from the file system listing and is finally deleted as soon as the file is closed).

Close the application that shows the PDF. The file will definitely disappear after a reboot.

One comment to the chmod-command: a implies ugo.